# Responsive dropdown menu - hide previously displayed menu items when screen size increased to breakpoint

Tags: jquery, css, drop-down-menu, hover, responsive-design

I am designing a responsive dropdown menu with markup similar to this:

```
<nav id="nav" role="navigation"> 
  <a href="#nav">Show navigation</a>
  <a href="#">Hide navigation</a>
  <ul>
    <li><a href="/landingpage.html">anchor link 1</a>
        <div class="show-hide">
            <div class="show">►</div>
            <div class="hide">▼</div>
        </div>
        <ul class="submenu">
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
            <li>list item</li>
        </ul>
    </li>
   etc...
  </ul>
</nav>
```

The anchor links are also hyperlinks to landing pages. On large screens the navigation is horizontal, and I'm using CSS to have the submenus display on hover so that the anchor links remain clickable.

CSS that controls hover:

```
#nav ul > li > .submenu {
display: none;
}

@media only screen and (min-width: 768px){
  #nav li:hover > .submenu {
    display:block;
  }
}
```

On small screens the navigation collapses to a vertical navigation menu bar that displays the anchor links, along with arrows to the right of the anchor links. The submenus (using jQuery slideToggle) display when these arrows are clicked. The anchor links themselves still point to their landing pages, though hovering over them no longer displays the submenu.

jQuery that controls slideToggle() on click:

```
$(".show-hide").click(function() {
  $(this).next('ul').slideToggle();
  $('div',this).toggle();
});
```

---

http://jsfiddle.net/NxDe8/3/ **jsfiddle of current iteration of menu**

---

**My problems arise when** the user interacts with the small-screen vertical version of the menu and then resizes the screen to trigger the large-screen horizontal version of the menu.

Starting on a small screen, the user clicks on the arrows to display the submenus. The user then resizes the window so that the large-screen horizontal navigation bar is displayed. The hover still works, but the submenus remain visible. If the user closes the submenus on the small screen before enlarging the window to trigger the large-screen horizontal menu, the submenus remain hidden, but hover no longer works to display submenus.

I've tried using jQuery instead of CSS to control the hover, binding the hover function to screen size and hiding submenus automatically on window size increase. This breaks after few resizings and clicks: http://jsfiddle.net/ps3Tq/4/

I've also tried binding the slideToggle() function to small window sizes, but in this case the submenus just bounce up and down without solving any problems.

I'm new to jQuery and I'm pretty stumped. Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Give this a go:

http://jsfiddle.net/NxDe8/4/

Basically I just made everything use jQuery instead of mixing.

JS:

```
$('#nav li').on('mouseenter', function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        $(this).find('.submenu').stop().slideDown();
    }
});

$('#nav li').on('mouseleave', function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        $(this).find('.submenu').stop().slideUp();
    }
});

$(window).on('resize', function() {
    if ($(window).width() > 768) {
        $('.submenu, .hide').hide();
        $('.show').show();

    }
});
```

CSS:

```
/* second level */

 #nav ul li .submenu {
    display: none;
    position: absolute;
}
```

Comment: Thank you, thank you, thank you! This works beautifully! Now to test across browsers and devices...